# FTC problem - Evaluate $\int_{4}^{16} \left[ \frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_{5}^{x} \left( 2\sqrt{t} - 1 \right) \ dt \right) \right] dx$

Tags: calculus

one of the FTC problems of a Calculus textbook suggests this small problem:

Evaluate the following:

$$\int_{4}^{16} \left[ \frac{d}{dx}  \left( \int_{5}^{x}  \left( 2\sqrt{t} - 1 \right) \ dt \right)  \right] dx $$

The suggested answer is

> Ans: $\frac{818}{3}$

I cannot agree with the result. Can anyone confirm the textbook error?

Thank you.

Comment: One more typo in a textbook !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $$\int_{4}^{16}\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{5}^{x}(2\sqrt t-1) dt\right)\right]dx$$
$$=\int_{4}^{16}\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\left[\frac{2t^{3/2}}{3/2}-t\right]_{5}^{x}\right)\right]dx$$
$$=\int_{4}^{16}\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{4}{3}x^{3/2}-x-\frac{4}{3}(5^{3/2})+5\right)\right]dx$$

$$=\int_{4}^{16}\left[2x^{1/2}-1\right]dx$$
$$=2\int_{4}^{16}x^{1/2}dx-\int_{4}^{16}dx$$

$$=2\left[\frac{x^{3/2}}{3/2}\right]_{4}^{16}-\left[x\right]_{4}^{16}$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}\left[16^{3/2}-4^{3/2}\right]-[16-4]$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}(64-8)-12=\color{red}{\frac{188}{3}}$$

Comment: sorry I see that I forgot a "-1" inside the integral, my mistake.

Comment: After inserting the "-1" I get 188/3. Do you agree @Harish?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right

Comment: thank you, this book is filled with careless mistakes, some correction is required.

Comment: May be, it would be faster to use the FTC.

Answer (score 1):

Since this exercise is about the FTC, remember that, if $$I=\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$$ $$\frac{dI}{dx}=f(x)$$ So, applied to the problem, you just need to compute $$\int_{4}^{16}  \left( 2\sqrt{x} - 1 \right) \, dx$$

I am sure that you can take from here and get the $\frac{188}{3}$ already reported.